# populating json pickerView error unexpected found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Tags: json, swift3

please don't answer me that I'm a donkey...but I'm going crazy with the migration of a project from Swift 1.2 to Swift 3 (that I'm trying to learn by myself).
The problem is that I'm running into an issue that I can't understand:

I'm reading a JSON from the web to retrieve some categories to load into a Picker View, but the app crashes when I try to serialize the JSON

```
    /////////////// PICKER VIEW

    func populatePicker(){

    let urlCat = URL(string: "http://www.direttaweb.it/geoApp/html5/JSON_cat.php)");

    let dataCat = try? Data(contentsOf: urlCat!);

    var errorCat: NSError?



    do {
       /* HERE CRASH -> */ if let jsonObjectCat = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataCat!, options: [] ) as? [String: AnyObject] {
    // parse JSON

    if let jsonObjectCat = jsonObjectCat as? [String: AnyObject] , errorCat == nil,

    let jsonDataCat = JSONValue.fromObject(jsonObjectCat as AnyObject)?["data"]?.array {
        for categoriaJSON in jsonDataCat {

            if let categoriaJSON = categoriaJSON.array,
                // 5
                let categoria = Categoria.fromJSONCAT(categoriaJSON) {

                categorie.append(categoria)


                    }
                }
            }
        self.pickerCategorie.delegate = self
        self.pickerCategorie.dataSource = self


        }
    }catch{
    print(errorCat!)
    }

   }
```

The strange thing is that few lines above, I'm doing the same thing with another object with a function that is almost the same (except for the array that I'm filling) and I got no issues...
Please let me know where I'm doing the mistake!

Comment: `dataCat` is `nil` because `Data(contentsOf: urlCat!);` failed and threw.

Comment: In Swift 3 the representation of a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]` and you are strongly discouraged from using synchronous `Data(contentsOf` to load data from a remote URL.

Comment: they also removed the C style for loop I want to die!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, thanks to your help i was able to make it work, and now the function become this:

```
func populatePicker(){

        let urlCat = "http://www.direttaweb.it/geoApp/html5/JSON_cat.php";



        let url = URL(string: urlCat)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (dataCat, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "errore nel json delle categorie")
            } else {
                do {


                    if let jsonObjectCat = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataCat!, options: [] ) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        // parse JSON


                        // 3
                        if let jsonObjectCat = jsonObjectCat as? [String: AnyObject] ,
                            // 4
                            let jsonDataCat = JSONValue.fromObject(jsonObjectCat as AnyObject)?["data"]?.array {
                            for categoriaJSON in jsonDataCat {

                                if let categoriaJSON = categoriaJSON.array,
                                    // 5
                                    let categoria = Categoria.fromJSONCAT(categoriaJSON) {

                                    print(categoria.categoria)
                                    self.categorie.append(categoria)

                                }

                            }
                        }
                        self.pickerCategorie.delegate = self
                        self.pickerCategorie.dataSource = self


                    }



                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            }.resume()

    }
```

but I'm experiencing another strange behavior: the items in the picker view become visibile only after I touch it...but why?
I try to load in the viewdidappear and in the viewdidload but nothing change ...